# Ways of writing an $n$-cycle as product of a $2$-cycle and $n-1$ cycle.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

We know that any $n$ cycle can be written as a product of a $2$-cycle and an $n-1$ cycle; but this decomposition is not unique: $(123)=(12)(23)$ and $(123)=(23)(31)$ [product taken from right to left operations].

**Q.** In how many ways we can write an $n$-cycle into product of a $2$-cycle and an $n-1$-cycle?

Comment: I think at least $2n$ ways when $n \geq 4$. You can have a transposition $(a_i \ a_{i+1})$ or $(a_n \ a_1)$ on either side of the $(n-1)$-cycle.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Let $C_n=C_{n-1}C_2$ be the respective product of cycles. Then $C_nC_2=C_{n-1}(C_2)^2=C_{n-1}.$ But the first product is a cycle of length $n-1$ iff $C_2$ swaps the neighbors of the cycle $C_n$. So the number of ways is $n$.